# composer: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages after moving on php 8

Tags: composer-php

Hi I'm migrate on the PHP 8 and update composer to the version 2. When I tried to update my dependances I got errors:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages
    Problem 1
     - prooph/service-bus is locked to version v6.2.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
     - prooph/service-bus v6.2.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 2
      - prooph/event-sourcing is locked to version v5.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - prooph/event-sourcing v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 3
        - prooph/pdo-event-store is locked to version v1.12.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - prooph/pdo-event-store v1.12.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 4
        - prooph/event-store-bus-bridge is locked to version v3.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - prooph/event-store-bus-bridge v3.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 5
        - prooph/snapshotter is locked to version v2.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - prooph/snapshotter v2.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 6
        - prooph/pdo-snapshot-store is locked to version v1.5.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - prooph/pdo-snapshot-store v1.5.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 7
        - zendframework/zend-escaper is locked to version 2.6.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - zendframework/zend-escaper 2.6.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 8
        - spatie/ssl-certificate-chain-resolver is locked to version 2.0.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - spatie/ssl-certificate-chain-resolver 2.0.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 9
        - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock is locked to version 4.3.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 10
        - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - ramsey/uuid 3.9.3 requires paragonie/random_compat ^1 | ^2 | 9.99.99 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].
        - ramsey/uuid is locked to version 3.9.3 and an update of this package was not requested."
```

As I understand this error mean that some of my packages are not ready for php 8. What can I do to update packages which are ready?

I tried to update composer.json for the prooph components

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
        "prooph/common" : "^4.0.0"
    }
```

to

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1 || ^8.0",
        "prooph/common" : "^4.0.0"
    }
```

and run command `composer.phar update --lock --with-all-dependencies` but it's not help

When I tried to update vimeo/psalm by "composer.phar update vimeo/psalm 4.4" I got the same error. Does it mean that prooph require old version of psalm and it not allow to update it?

How to resolve this problem and update all which are ready?

My composer.json file:

```
 {
        "require": {
            "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": ">=2.8",
            "prooph/service-bus": "^6.2",
            "prooph/event-sourcing": "^5.6",
            "prooph/event-store": "^7.5",
            "prooph/pdo-event-store": "^1.10",
            "prooph/event-store-bus-bridge": "^3.3",
            "prooph/snapshotter": "^2.1",
            "prooph/pdo-snapshot-store": "^1.5",
            "psr/container": "^1.0",
            "zendframework/zend-escaper": "^2.6",
            "spatie/ssl-certificate-chain-resolver": "^2.0",
            
            "webmozart/glob": "^4.1",
            "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
            "webmozart/assert": "^1.5",
            "vimeo/psalm":  "^3.5.1",
            "sebastian/diff": "^3.0",
            "psr/log": "^1.1",
            "phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "^1.0",
            "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^4.3",
            "phpdocumentor/reflection-common": "^2.0",
            "openlss/lib-array2xml": "^1.0",
            "ocramius/package-versions": "^1.4",
            "nikic/php-parser": "^4.2",
            "netresearch/jsonmapper": "^1.6",
            "felixfbecker/language-server-protocol": "^1.4",
            "felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc": "^3.0",
            "composer/xdebug-handler": "^1.3",
            "amphp/byte-stream": "^1.6",
            "amphp/amp": "^2.2",
            "symfony/service-contracts": "^1.1",
            "symfony/polyfill-php73": "^1.11",
            "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.11",
            "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.12",
            "symfony/console": "^4.3",
            
            "ramsey/uuid": "^3.8",
              "ext-json": "*",
              "ext-openssl": "*",
              "ext-mysqli": "*",
              "ext-dom": "*",
              "ext-curl": "*",
          "ext-pcntl": "*",
          "ext-posix": "*",
            "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.1",
            "symfony/routing": "^5.1",
            "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^2.2",
            "react/promise": "^2.8",
            "psr/event-dispatcher": "^1.0",
          "ext-ftp": "*",
          "ext-iconv": "*"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                            "vendor/acme_nc/ACMECert.php",
                            "vendor/roundcube/roundcubeAutoLogin.php"
                        ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, the following two lines tell it all:

> - prooph/service-bus is locked to version v6.2.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - prooph/service-bus v6.2.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.

According to that [package's information](https://packagist.org/packages/prooph/service-bus), there is no version compatible with PHP 8. And as written in a [blog post](https://www.sasaprolic.com/2018/08/the-future-of-prooph-components.html) by one of the maintainers, there will be no new versions of this package.

---

Updating the other packages should be possible by updating your `composer.json`. As you haven't shared the current state of your configuration, it's not possible to tell you what you need to change, but the most simplest way is taking one line after the other, check for updates on packagist.org, and adjust the version constraint. But be warned that it's pretty likely that you run some major upgrades. Having a good test suite helps to check which upgrades cause which problems

Comment: I added composer.json

Do You mean to change version of package in composer.json file, or try to do

composer update package/name new_version?

Comment: If you want to update a package beyond the constraints given in composer.json, you need to update composer.json

Comment: I updated composer.json to "vimeo/psalm":  "^4.4" and run composer update vimeo/psalm and got the same errors

Comment: Which are "the same errors"? Through updating any other package, you still cannot use PHP 8, as each and every package has to be compatible

Comment: Thank  you! I had misunderstanding of the composer.json file. That was my main problem. I changed version of required packages in the file and updated them.